# Can't open an excel file using cmd

Tags: c#

I am new to C# programming so, I am sorry if I make a beginner's mistake.
I am trying to write an app that when the user clicks a button it opens the OpenFileDialog and he must choose a ".xlsx" file and the program should open this file in excel.
Here is my code:

```
OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
openfile.Filter = ("Excel files |*.xlsx");
penfile.FilterIndex = 1;
String file_name;
file_name = openfile.FileName;
if(openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string cmd= "/C start excel.exe " + file_name;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", cmd);
}
```

The problem is it only opens excel but without the file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked that the contents of `file_name` are correct?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Read `openfile.FileName` after `ShowDialog()`... You would've noticed the empty filename if you'd set a breakpoint in the `if()` block.

Comment: use Process.Start and use the Open verb.

Comment: Please figure out on what step you get errors as you for some reason want to use multiple layer to open file. Side note: `Process.Start(file_name)` is likely enough (assuming it is actually xls/xlsx).

Comment: you are actually assigning `file_name` before you are showing the dialog. Try to assign the value after the `openfile.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I forgot that I must put file_name after the dialog has finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you should read the file selected by OpenFileDialog after closing the dialog, not before ShowDialog

```
...
if(openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   file_name = openfile.FileName;
   ....
```

Comment: This worked , Thanks. Sorry for that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Steve's answer:

You don't need the extra command stuff. This will also open any file for you.

```
if(openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    file_name = openfile.FileName;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file_name);
}
```

---

Or if you want to make sure its an excel file:

```
if(openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    file_name = openfile.FileName;

    if (file_name.ToUpper().Contains(".XLS")
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file_name);
}
```

Comment: "Any File" As long as it has a default program.

Comment: Thanks for the tip man.